# Where to find the resource UUID of Azure DevOps organization

Tags: azure-devops

I want to get the access token for Azure DevOps as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#q-can-i-use-a-service-principal-or-managed-identity-with-azure-cli).

```
$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 --query "accessToken" --output tsv
```

It's mentioned in the example that `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` is the resource UUID of Azure DevOps, but where can I find it? I checked the organization settings and didn't find anything, and billing is not set up for me as I'm using the free tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you were using Azure CLI to generate `Microsoft Entra` (formerly known as **A**zure **A**ctive **D**irectory) token to access the Azure DevOps resource; the app ID of `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` was visible in the Microsoft Entra ID(AAD) that your organization was connected to.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, found it where you mentioned!